# GCC on Mojave: The compiler cannot read the includes at -I /opt/X11/include/X11

Tags: c, gcc, include, x11

Trying to compile with GCC on Mojave and am getting an error.

```
gcc  -g -ansi -c test_scroll_images_3x.c -I /opt/X11/include/X11
```

```
test_scroll_images_3x.c:17:11: fatal error: 'X11/Xlib.h' file not found
# include <X11/Xlib.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I have several subroutines like this, and all have the same problem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System#Competitors

Comment: I found another Xlib.h in /usr/X11R6/include/X11, and it won't read that one either. I sure hope someone knows a little about this. This might have come about because I installed Mojave over 10.13, and gfortran just a few days ago.